# how to fire mouse event click on tab

Tags: reactjs, antd

**ReactJS**: I trying to fire mouse event clicking on **evolution metrics** tab but not working.How to do it.

```
<Tabs type="card">
               <TabPane tab="evolution metrics" key="1" onClick={handleTab}>
                 Content of tab 1
                </TabPane>
</Tab>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ant design Tabs onClick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811590/ant-design-tabs-onclick-function)

Answer (score 0):

Might need to see more of the surrounding code, like the definition of `handleTab`, but sometimes what works is putting `onClick={() => handleTab()}`

Answer (score 0):

because TabPane not support props onClick: https://ant.design/components/tabs/#Tabs.TabPane

You can use `onChange` on `Tabs` component: https://ant.design/components/tabs/#Tabs

```
<Tabs onChange={handleTab} />
```